# design pattern - dispatcher

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I have a use-case like the following:

Lets say I have an  enumType Foo (possible values A,B,C).
Suppose I have

```
Class Bar{
 List<Foo> foos; // list of Foo objects where each object can have 1 of 3 possible values
 long id;
 String name;
 String num;
 ...
}
```

My clients would call a method "dispatch" in Dispatcher class, which takes in "Bar".

Now for each (Foo foo : foos), it delegates the actual dispatch to specific types (i.e. I want a seperate handler for A, B and C type of messages).

Secondly, the message which has to be dispatched should be created differently for A, B and C. Based on the value of foo, we pick up the message from templates and insert "name", "num" as obtained from Bar).

Are there specific patterns I am looking at for this design? How should I be designing such a system. would appreciate a discussion or pointers to existing patterns or best practices.

Comment: It is confusing because Foo is opaque.  What is the structure of Foo?  And why do you have Bar there?  Is that the Dispatcher?  And how do they relate to A, B, and C?  (Part of the confusion is all five of the names are meaningless).  More specifically, are A, B, and C different messages that are received by the Dispatcher?  Or does the Dispatcher receive a Foo and then decide to create A, B, or C, and send each to a separate Handler?

Answer (score 0):

Use polymorphism.

```
enum Foo {
    VALUE1 {
        @Override public void someMethod() {...}
    },
    VALUE2 {
        @Override public void someMethod() {...}
    },
    VALUE 3 {
        @Override public void someMethod() {...}
    };

    public abstract void someMethod();

}
```

Comment: I meant more like the class hierarchy and design with a seperate dispatcher each for messages of type A, B and C etc.